# Maui close ios application programmatically

Tags: ios, maui

How to close application in **IOS** or **Maccatalyst** from code in **MAUI**?
In app i warn user that app is about to be closed and after that i used **exit(0)**  previously, it works in debug, but as apple docs say its unwanted behavior, moreover it does not really kill the app, rather just places it into background.

Comment: Apple prohibits this in iOS apps

Answer (score 2):

This approach is not allowed in Apple, and the app store will reject your app. The recommended method is to display a warning to the user, indicating the nature of the problem and possible actions for the user. You can refer to Apple's Q&A: [How do I programmatically quit my iOS application?](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1561/_index.html)